# How do I instantiate a JAXBElement<String> object?

Tags: java, jaxb

I need to create one of these as the interface requires it. Can someone please let me know how to create one, as there doesn't seem to be a constructor defined?

Answer (score 222, accepted):

When you imported the WSDL, you should have an `ObjectFactory` class which should have bunch of methods for creating various input parameters.

```
ObjectFactory factory = new ObjectFactory();
JAXBElement<String> createMessageDescription = factory.createMessageDescription("description");
message.setDescription(createMessageDescription);
```

Answer (score 12):

```
ObjectFactory fact = new ObjectFactory();   
JAXBElement<String> str = fact.createCompositeTypeStringValue("vik");    
comp.setStringValue(str);
CompositeType retcomp = service.getDataUsingDataContract(comp);
System.out.println(retcomp.getStringValue().getValue());
```

Answer (score 8):

Here is how I do it. You will need to get the namespace URL and the element name from your generated code.

```
new JAXBElement(new QName("http://www.novell.com/role/service","userDN"),
                new String("").getClass(),testDN);
```

Comment: Itse better to use ObjectFactory class as mentioned below rather than using JAXBElement constructor

Answer (score 6):

Other alternative:

```
JAXBElement<String> element = new JAXBElement<>(new QName("Your localPart"),
                                                String.class, "Your message");
```

Then:

```
System.out.println(element.getValue()); // Result: Your message
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you think there's no constructor.  See [the API](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXBElement.html#JAXBElement(javax.xml.namespace.QName,%20java.lang.Class,%20T)).